MAUI File picker Operation not permitted on MacOS
When I try to select a file in a FilePicker on MAUI I get an error even with the environments.plist updated as required in the MAUI documentation
Error message :
2024-06-11 11:53:58.471 ProjectManagement[50242:2538916] Failed to create an FPSandboxingURLWrapper for file:///Users/name/Downloads/insert.csv. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.app-sandbox.read-write for '/Users/name/Downloads/insert.csv': Operation not permitted" UserInfo={NSDescription=couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.app-sandbox.read-write for '/Users/name/Downloads/insert.csv': Operation not permitted} 
Method for file picker
public static async Task InsertAsync()
        {
            var options = new PickOptions
            {
                PickerTitle = "Sélectionnez un fichier CSV"
            };
            var file = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);


            if (file != null)
            {
                ...
            }
        }


Environmen.plist with keys
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.music.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.personal-information.photos-library</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.app-sandbox.read-write</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

I've also tried to add com.apple.app-sandbox.read-write and com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only in the environment.plist however the operation is still not permitted...

Which iOS version are you using? Does this problem also occur in other versions?

I assume you meant the macOS version. I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.5 and haven't tried on other versions.

Have you tried <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key> <true/>?

No, I hadn't tried it before but it worked, thank you very much

Adding <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key> <true/> in Environmen.plist solved the problem
